# Calling PUT API in Restangular

Tags: angularjs

This is my API  '/api/comments/{id}'

The above API requires id as well as json data.

I tried the following code but it doesnt seems to work.

```
Restangular.one('api/comments/'+commentUID).put($scope.updateCommentData).then(function (responseData){

                        });
```

I need to send request payload with the put call

```
$scope.updateCommentData = {
                          "CommentUID": commentUID,
                          "AssetUID": $scope.currentAsset.AssetUID,
                          "Note":note,
                          "VisibilityEnum": 2,
                          "Ver": version
                        };
```

Can any one help me...

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using

```
Restangular.one('api/comments/'+commentUID).customPUT($scope.updateCommentData).then(function (response) {});
```

Thanks for your help

Please refer this link: [Restangular - PUT request payload is being sent as query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557588/restangular-put-request-payload-is-being-sent-as-query-string-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
Restangular.one('api/comments', commentUID).put($scope.updateCommentData).then(function (responseData){

                    });
```

here is the link https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

Comment: Can you please check what url get called in console/network

Comment: Correct url is called in console, but it is giving me Bad Request error.